# Need to create a page with all the image in the blog: Blogger template editing

Tags: image, api, blogger

I'm developing a blogger blog. The client asked for a dynamic slider that randomly can show all the photos posted in the blog or some selected photos by specifiic time range. But I find no way or api to access those photo that can be used in the blogger template editing. 
If you know any option to do that please help. 
Thanks